# How can master process and child process share listen fd and accept new connection in golang?

Tags: go

I've been stucked with this issue for days:

I listen a port with a fd in master process. Then I fork a new child process which inhert the fd.

I don't want to kill the master process, and How can I accept connections no mattter in master process or child process????

I has try somes: If master process is alive, only it can accept connection; it is killed, child do it.

My golang's version is 1.6.2.

Thx, Look forward to your reply！！！

Comment: why share fd? reuse port should be the the thing you need.

Comment: I want to gracefull restart golang server.I listen a fd in master process, fork a child process inherit the fd and only the child accept connection.When i restart, I want to firstly fork new master process and child process which inherit the listen fd from old master's listen fd.Do this, in any time listen port is alive. And why two processes alive: I want to master monitor child, if child process crash, master process can start a new child process inmediately.

Comment: it's not a problem, add a system scope lock before `accept` in you processes.

Comment: I has try somes: If master process is alive, only it can accept connection; it is killed, child do it.

Comment: sorry, I check again, It is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Kill off your master - let your child handle the new connections (the child will become the master).

http://grisha.org/blog/2014/06/03/graceful-restart-in-golang/

As a side note...

I did this for a little while, graceful restarting the service on dedicated servers and VMs.  But I always ran into issues with Canary Testing and Blue/Green deployments, trying out new code in a staging environment before I flipped the switch for it to go live.  It gets rather difficult once you are running 200 instances of your app (or really, more than 2 or 3!).

I always thought it was imperative that I manage all connections and don't drop a single package on my dedicated VMs.  But learning to use the managed cloud tools Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk and Azure Websites for packaging up executables (and now, Docker support in Beanstalk) and deploying them on new VMs, and throwing away the old VMs, it really freed me from this burden at scale.  I just let Amazon handle the "spinning up" and "shutting down" of the docker instances on different VMs, deleting the old ones.  It will deploy your new code on the new VMs, and will keep the old ones active until there are no more connections through the load balancer.  Then it finally shuts down the old ones.  Zero dropped connections, zero issues.

By switching to these managed approaches, you gain the ability to test our code in limited traffic (say 5% of traffic directed to the new version of the services, where you can canary test), you can gracefully roll out new versions, or even do a hard switch of all new connections going to the new system.

Just trying to save you a few years of heartache and lessons learned.  :)